# Perguntas muito específicas e triviais devem ser mantidas?

Tags: debate

Acredito que muitos já se depararam com perguntas muito específicas e triviais, como por exemplo [um erro de falta de aspas em um atributo de um form](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191483/notice-undefined-index-em-variavel-files-upload-php/191583#191583) ou erros de digitação mesmo, que está no código da pessoa que fez a pergunta e não é um problema comum. São perguntas que geralmente o usuário que fez a pergunta descobre o erro e responde (acho que maioria) ou alguém responde apenas com a correção do código.

Fico em dúvida se estas perguntas são mantidas no site, ou se há uma recomendação de sinalização para esse tipo de pergunta. E cada dia vejo mais esse tipo de pergunta, acredito que pela popularidade do site estar aumentando.

Na verdade a intenção não é nem inibir a pessoa a perguntar muitas vezes ela não conhece o Stack Overflow e é até bom ela ter essa experiência de ter a pergunta fechada pra ver como funciona a comunidade. O que fico preocupado e ficar muito "lixo" no site. Perguntas que não ajudam mais ninguem.

Comment: Existe uma opção de fechamento para isso. Fora do escopo > "Esse problema **não pode ser reproduzido**, ou é um **erro de digitação**. Mesmo dentro do escopo do site, **sua solução dificilmente seria útil a outros usuários no futuro**. Problemas assim podem ser evitados com a criação de um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável."

Comment: Por falar nisso reabrir para fecha-la corretamente agora ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eh mesmo haha

Comment: Feito, só falta o pessoal votar corretamente, infelizmente eu não posso votar mais nessa pergunta, o sistema me limita a um voto de fechamento por pergunta, a não ser que a AP edite ela (eu acho).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acho que nem editando... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346064/why-cant-i-vote-to-close-a-question-which-was-reopened?cb=1

Comment: @EMBarbosa obrigado!